# Problems connecting to chat server in a game, maybe related to DNS or Winsock

Tags: windows, dns, connection

#### Problem

Okay, so I don't want to give away the game because it is in beta currently. But here is the scoop. I have been trolling their forums for quite some time now and quite a few people seem to have had this problem in the past.

**Basically everything is working except the chat.** In the logs I can find the spot where it says attempting to connect to `chat.gameswebsitegoeshere.com` and every time it fails.

#### Attempted solutions

On the forums it seems that a lot of people that have had issues similar to this have fixed it by typing:

```
netsh winsock reset catalog
```

I have done this 5-6 times and restarted the computer every time. No go. Someone else on the forums has recommended typing:

```
netsh int ip reset.log hit
```

But `cmd.exe` says

> unrecognized or incomplete command.

Originally the error log was saying "invalid SRV" along with "connection refused".

#### DNS issues

I changed my DNS to Verizon `4.2.2.1` from AT&T and that fixed the "invalid SRV". I noticed that sometimes when I first go to a website, it won't load. It will say

> Oops! Google Chrome could not find www.popsci.com

then I refresh and it loads.

When I went to reinstall the game when it started trying to download the game files I had to retry 3 times before it actually connected to `dl.beta.gameswebsitegoeshere.com`.

I removed Malwarebytes and SUPERAntiSpyware, turned on/turned off Windows firewall. I port forwarded 5222 on my router (5222 is what is used by the chat).

I am running Windows 7 Ultimate. I have a Motorola NVG510 router/modem.

Comment: Can you change your dns servers to 8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4 and check if it persists ?

Comment: well i dont seem to have the problems with websites not loading anymore, however i still can not chat in that game.

Comment: actually it just happened again using 8.8.8.8 and alternate 8.8.4.4